# How to check if a Notification key exists in Firebase Cloud Messaging server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging in my app. I want to know how to check whether a notification key exists in the FCM server.

Scenario:

When the user login from a device for first time, we check if the notification key exists for the user in our server db. If not, we create a notification group in FCM server using the username as notification key name and device token is added to the notification group and the notification key is saved to our server db corresponding to the user. As in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications) link.

When the user logs out, we remove the device token of the user's current device from the notification group. But if the last notification key in a group is removed, the notification key will be deleted from the server.

Next time when the user logs in, as the notification key already exists for the user in our server db we tries to add the device token to the notification group in FCM server with that notification key. But if we get the error response like "Notification key does not exist!.

If we could check if the notification key exists in FCM server we could create a new notification group instead of trying to add to the token to the non existing notification group and fail.

So, how to check  if a Notification key exists in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to manage the the existence of a device group associated with a user yourself. When the user logs out and you remove the final token from the device group then you should note that the device group is empty and thus when the user logs in again you should create a new device group.

Comment: Yeah! I think that is the way to go. Keeping a notification group token count   for each user will be the solution for this. When user logs out remove the token from fcm server and decrease the count and vice versa when logging in. So we will only have to check if the count is zero for checking if notification key exists.

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching head here but managing yourself is doable